# Can not enter password in Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, ftp

I can not enter my pass word.
My shell script is here.

```
#!/bin/bash

expect -c "
set timeout 2
spawn ftp ${HOST}
expect \"Name\(${HOST}:root\):\"
send ${USER}\n
expect \"Password:\"
send ${PASS}\n
interact
"
```

I can enter user-name, but password is not work....

like this return.

```
spawn ftp ******
Connected to ****** (******).
220 (vsFTPd 2.2.2)
Name (******:root): ${USER}
331 Please specify the password.
Password:[root@........ bin]#
```

I think I send password... Could you please help me?

Thank you.

**SOLVE MY QUESTION**

I think it is easy for me to use this.

```
it is easy for me to use this.
#!/bin/sh

SERVER=$1
USER=$2
PASS=$3
FILE=$4

ftp -n <<END
open $SERVER
user $USER $PASS
cd /tmp
binary
prompt
mput $FILE
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to prompt password and send it to variable

echo -n "Enter Password:"
read PASS